# Code splitting with Rollup and Svelte changes all chunk names with new hashes even with no modifications

Tags: hash, split, svelte, rollup

I'm using ***Svelte*** and ***Rollup*** with **code splitting**, and here are some parts of my ***rollup.config.js***:

```
    input: {
        'boot': 'src/boot.js',
        'app': 'src/app.js',
        'agency': 'src/modules/agency.js',
        'buyer': 'src/modules/buyer.js',
        'buyer-group': 'src/modules/buyer-group.js',
        'investor': 'src/modules/investor.js',
        'management-unit': 'src/modules/management-unit.js',
        'platform': 'src/modules/platform.js',
        'supplier': 'src/modules/supplier.js',
        'tables': 'src/modules/tables.js',
        'pt-BR': 'src/core/locale/pt-BR.js',
        'en': 'src/core/locale/en.js',
        'external-svelte-package': 'node_modules/external-svelte-package/src/index.js'
    },

    output: {
        sourcemap: false,
        format: 'esm',
        dir: `${baseDir}/js`,
        entryFileNames: '[name]-[hash].js',
        chunkFileNames: '[name].[hash].js'
    },
```

Rollup generates chunks with names containing hashes (e.g. `investor-fa42bee8.js`).

If I run build script again, with no modifications in any file of the project, all the chunks are generated with new hashes, and this behavior harms client **long term cache**.

How can I change this behavior and grants same hash for all chunks that are not modified?

Any help will be wlcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the hashes change, something in your sources changes. Likely a plugin or a banner that contains a timestamp or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, Lukas, but I made a program that compares line to line one of the chunks generated in two consecutive buildings with no modification, and the program show that the contents of the chunks are exactly the same.

Comment: Without a reproduction this is unfortunately hard to debug. It should not happen but otherwise I can only guess and this will no lead far.
Something you can try: Add a simple plugin that just implements a `moduleParsed` hook and check if the `code` properties of the modules are identical between runs.

Comment: Another possibility is that a plugin uses the `augmentChunkHash` hook in a suboptimal way.

Comment: Lukas,

Thanks again for your quick answer, your attention and your patience.

I was struggling with it until today, and when I removed rollup-plugin-postcss from rollup.confg.js, the problem was solved. 

The strange thing is that, like I said, I created a program that compares all files generated by both build processes, and it showed no differences. Maybe this program had a bug.

Anyway, the problem was solved and, once again, thanks a lot.