# File names hash always changing on every build even those files has no changes

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

I'm using Rollup in Svelte app, where on every build it changes the file names hash.

But I don't want to change the hash if that file has no changes to keep **long term cache**.
How can I configure that in rollupjs?

Found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896227/code-splitting-with-rollup-and-svelte-changes-all-chunk-names-with-new-hashes-ev), but didn't get any hints.